# how to create custom edit , new,save buttons using apex class and visual force

Tags: visualforce-component

I want to create something like this 
                     new|save (custom buttons)

edit|delete(custom buttons)    contact firstname lastname phone email

GUI should look like this all this fields in page block table 
I want to create all this functionality

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Ruchika. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Steps-
1.Create Visualforce page with controller(overide standard pages with visualforce page).
2.Make command button on visual force pageblock section 
3. Call controller method for save,del,edit,new and have your custom logic there for each functionality.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that will help you.
Custom controller:

```
public class MyController {

    private final Account account;

    public MyController() {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update account;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="myController" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Congratulations {!$User.FirstName}">
            You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

As you can see there is save button on VF page which call controller action Save.

For more detailed steps refer this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

If you are new to SFDC codding then i would suggest you complete trailhead module - https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/visualforce_fundamentals